# SAS: How to run a loop on a set of input variables for a function

Tags: variables, automation, sas

I'm basically trying to make a program that can extract the relevant variables from a CSV file and perform stationarity tests on these timeseries variables without having to type out the variable names manually. I'm fairly new and maybe there's redundancies, but I've basically embeded the variable names into variable1, variable2, etc...

So when I've tested the ADF macro and input the variable as:

```
  proc arima data=&y;
identify var= &variable1 stationarity =(adf = 3);
run;
```

it works, but I'm struggling to automate this process and would appreciate any help you could offer. Thanks.

Here is what I have to far:

```
proc import datafile=".....csv"
 out=data
 dbms=csv
 replace;
 getnames=yes;
run;

proc contents data=data out=contents noprint;
run;

data contents;
set contents(keep = name);
if Name = "Quarter" then delete; 
run;

data _NULL_;
set contents;
call symputx(cats('variable',strip(_n_)),name);
run;

data want;
   do i=1 to 4;
   expert=symget(cats('variable',i));


     output;
   end;
  run;

%macro ADF(y = ,x = );

proc arima data=&y;
identify var= &x stationarity =(adf = 3);
run;

%mend ADF;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close... You just need to look into `call execute`.  It will allow you to build commands and have them execute after the datastep finishes.

In the below code we're building the calls to the macro that we want to run.  They will be exected as instructions after the datastep has finished processing.  This will allow us to use values within the datastep to build the commands:

```
data want;
   do i=1 to 4;
     expert=symget(cats('variable',i));
     call execute (cats('%ADF(y=data,x=',expert,');'));
   end;
 run;
```

There are other ways to do it but this is the simplest based on what you already have in place.

Just make sure your macro is defined prior to running the datastep.

Comment: Hi Robert, thank you for explaining this to me! Really appreciate it :)

Comment: @rayven1lk No problems.  If you got it working and it answered your question don't forget to please mark the answer as accepted.  Thanks.